# Proving that a k stage pipeline can be at most k times faster than that of a nonpipelined one

Tags: algorithm, pipeline, pipelining

I roughly (abstractly) understand why pipeline is `k` times faster than non-pipelined one (like this way):

1. K stage pipeline dividing the circuit into k parts.
2. Each stage has the same transistor delay (Ideally)
3. So it is K times faster.(like using conveyor belt system on car factory)

But I cannot understand this mathematical expression:

```
clock cycle time = t 
number of command = n  
speedup = (n*k*t)/((k-1)*t+n*t) = (n*k*t)/(k*t+(n-1)*t)

if n -> infinite: speedup is k
```

What I don't know is:  What ((k-1)*t+n*t) means?

I can just understand `(nkt)` means non-pipelined time, so I believe `((k-1)*t+n*t)` should be the pipedlined time.

But, why `((k-1)*t+n*t)` is pipelined time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were correct - `(k-1)*t+n*t` is the time for executing `n` command in pipeline.

You should think of it as follow:

In the first `(k-1)` cycle (`t`) the pipe is filling up. After that time, 0 commends has been fully execute but all the pipe is filled.

From now on, every cycle `t` you will have new command who finished to execute (because of the pipeline effect) -> therefor, the `n*t`.

In total, after `(k-1)*t + n*t` is the time for execute `n` command in pipeline.

Hope that make it more clear!